# Class avg results in 0 from searching students in binary search tree enrolled in courses

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree

This is a homework assignment, and i'm pretty stumped on why this bug is occuring. I have a binary search tree (Roster) in which student objects are added to. Students are then placed in courses (added with linked list). I was able to add students into the roster and place the students in courses and print those. However, when I try to find the average grade of students I just keep getting the output as 0. I believe the max is not adding properly and integer is a higher value resulting in the output being 0.0. I added other print methods and max is printing as 0.0 and counter is printing as 3. Any idea's why?

Output:

```
List of all students:  11111 11112 11113 11114 11115 11116 
11114 found
Students enrolled in Math161: 11111 11112 11114 
11112 classes: Math161 Grade: 70 CS146 Grade: 90 CS105 Grade: 85 
Average grade of Math161 is 0.0
0.0 3
```

Homework5.java / main:

```
package homework5;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Homework5 {

    static Roster rost = new Roster();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        addStudent();
        displayAllStudents();
        lookupStudent("11114");
        addCourse();
        System.out.print("Students enrolled in Math161: ");
        displayStudents("Math161");
        System.out.println();
        displayCourses("11112");
        getCourseAverage("Math161");

    }

    // add students to the roster
    static void addStudent() {
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11111", "Jon", "Benson"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11112", "Erick", "Hooper"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11113", "Sam", "Shultz"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11114", "Trent", "Black"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11115", "Michell", "Waters"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11116", "Kevin", "Johnson"));
    }

    // display all students in the roster
    static void displayAllStudents() {
        rost.displayAllStudents();
    }

    // lookup a student in the roster
    static void lookupStudent(String id) {
        if (rost.find(id) != null) {
            System.out.println(id + " found");
        } else {
            System.out.println(id + " not found");
        }
    }

    // add courses to the roster
    static void addCourse() {
        rost.addCourse("11111", new Course("CS116", 80));
        rost.addCourse("11111", new Course("Math161", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("Math161", 70));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("CS146", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("CS105", 85));
        rost.addCourse("11113", new Course("CS216", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("CIS255", 75));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("CS216", 80));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("Math161", 60));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("COMM105", 90));
    }

    // display students enrolled in a given course id
    static void displayStudents(String courseId) {
        rost.displayStudents(courseId);
    }

    // display courses taken by a student
    static void displayCourses(String id) {
        rost.displayCourses(id);
    }

    // display the average grade for a student
    static void getCourseAverage(String courseId) {
        rost.getCourseAverage(courseId);
    }

}
```

Student.class:

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    String id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    double max;

    LinkedList<Course> courses = new LinkedList<>();

    Student(String id, String fName, String lName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setName(String lName) {
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student other) {    
        return this.getId().compareTo(other.getId());
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        courses.add(course);
    }

    public LinkedList<Course> getCourseList() {
        return courses;
    }

    public boolean hasCourse(String courseId) {
        // Enhanced for loop
        // Iterate through courses Linked List and print each course
        for (Course course : courses) {
            // if courseId is equal to courseId at the current courseId
            // return true
            if (courseId.equals(course.getCourseId())) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void getClassAverage(String courseId) {


        for (Course course : courses) {
            if (hasCourse(courseId)) {
                max += course.getGrade();
            }
        }
    }

    public void printCourses() {
        for (Course course : courses) {
            System.out.print(course.getCourseId() + 
                    " Grade: " + course.getGrade() + " ");
        }
    }

    public void printAverage(String courseId, int avg) {
        getClassAverage(courseId);
        System.out.println(avg);
    }
}

class Course {

    String id;  // course id
    int grade;

    Course(String id, int grade) {
        this.id = id;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getCourseId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setId(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

}
```

Roster.class:

```
class Roster {

    Student root;
    int numStudents;

    BST<Student> roster = new BST<>();

    public Roster() {
        root = null;
        numStudents = 0;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student st) {
        roster.insert(st);
        numStudents++;
    }

    public void displayAllStudents() {
        roster.traverse(2);
    }

    public Student find(String id) {
        return roster.find(id);
    }

    public void addCourse(String id, Course course) {
        Student student = roster.find(id);
        student.addCourse(course);      
    }

    public void displayStudents(String courseId) {
        roster.printCourse(courseId);
    }

    public void displayCourses(String id) {
        Student student = roster.find(id);
        System.out.print(id + " classes: ");
        student.printCourses();
    }

    public void getCourseAverage(String courseId) {
        roster.getAverage(courseId);
    }

}
```

BST.java:

```
package homework5;

class BST<Roster extends Comparable> {

    private Node root;
    double avg;
    double max;
    int counter;

    public BST() {
        root = null;
    }

    // Generic find method
    public Student find(String id) {

        Node current = root;

        // Loop until e.compare to current element is not equal to 0
        while (id.compareTo(current.element.getId()) != 0) {
            //!!! implement
            // if e.compare is less than 0 set current to current.left
            if (id.compareTo(current.element.getId()) < 0) {
                current = current.left;
            } // else if current is 0 or greater than 0 set current 
            // to current.right
            else {
                current = current.right;
            }
            // if current is null, return null
            if (current == null) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        // return current value when loop ends
        return current.element;

    }

    public void insert(Student st) {
        Node newNode = new Node(st);

        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } else {
            Node current = root;
            Node parent = null;

            while (true) {
                parent = current;
                if (st.getId().compareTo(current.element.getId()) < 0) {
                    current = current.left;
                    if (current == null) {
                        parent.left = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    current = current.right;
                    if (current == null) {
                        parent.right = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printCourse(String course) {
        printCourseHelper(root, course);
    }

    public void printCourseHelper(Node n, String course) {

        if (n.element.hasCourse(course)) {
            System.out.print(n.element.getId() + " ");
        }

        if (n.left != null) {
            printCourseHelper(n.left, course);
        }

        if (n.right != null) {
            printCourseHelper(n.right, course);
        }

    }

    public void getAverage(String course) {
        getAverageHelper(root, course);
        avg = max / counter;
        System.out.println("\nAverage grade of " + course + " is " + avg);
        System.out.println(max + " " + counter);
    }

    public void getAverageHelper(Node n, String course) {

        if (n.element.hasCourse(course)) {
            n.element.getClassAverage(course);
            counter++;
        }

        if (n.left != null) {
            getAverageHelper(n.left, course);
        }

        if (n.right != null) {
            getAverageHelper(n.right, course);
        }

    }

    public void traverse(int traverseType) {
        switch (traverseType) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("\nPreorder traversal: ");
                // call preOrder(root) and implement preOrder()
                preOrder(root);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("\nList of all students:  ");
                inOrder(root);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("\nPostorder traversal: ");
                // call postOrder(root) and implement postOrder()
                postOrder(root);
                break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Recursive method - traverse generic BST 
    // While root is not equal to null visit left node and print value
    // of root, then visit right node. Repeat until root becomes null
    private void inOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            inOrder(localRoot.left);
            System.out.print(localRoot.element.getId() + " ");
            inOrder(localRoot.right);
        }
    }

    // Recursive method - traverse generic BST 
    // While root is not equal to null print the value of the root
    // and visit left then right nodes. Repeat until root becomes null
    private void preOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
            preOrder(localRoot.left);
            preOrder(localRoot.right);
        }
    }

    // Recursive method - traverse generic BST 
    // While root is not equal to null visit left node and visit
    // the right node and print value of root. Repeat until root becomes null
    private void postOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            postOrder(localRoot.left);
            postOrder(localRoot.right);
            System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
        }
    }

}

class Node {

    protected Student element;
    protected Node left;
    protected Node right;

    public Node(Student st) {
        element = st;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show us the BST implementation of getAverage(String id)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant to post the BST code as well. It's there now.